# How to determine the accuracy of correlation preformed between two indicators?

Tags: r, correlation

I did a Pearson correlation analysis of CO2 emission(in Kt) with around 360 variables and found out that the correlation between CO2 emission and agricultural machinery is around 0.95(which is the highest correlation i found) and the correlation between CO2 and urban population is 0.30.
I find it difficult to believe that correlation between agricultural machinery and CO2 emission is much greater than correlation between CO2 emission and urban population.
Is there any way to determine how accurate my correlation values are?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must consider is the "level" at which these different variables are measured. Are CO2 emissions measured at the country level? Regional? At what level is agricultural machinery measured?  By country?  Also, are these variables measured at the same time.  Generally, I'd first pay attention to the definitions of these measures and their respective validity.